# mysqldump bad arguments order?

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, process

Windows

I try to backup database by creating process in c# and i'm passing this arguments to the process:

```
--column-statistics=0 --user=natesta --password="123" mydbfortesting > "D:\\outputdir\\mydbfortesting_dump.sql"
```

But i got error: `mysqldump: Couldn't find table: ">"`

I can't find any information about this, something change in arguments order?

Answer (score 1):

After i changed `>` to `-r` it starts working.

```
--column-statistics=0 --user=natesta --password="123" mydbfortesting -r "D:\\outputdir\\mydbfortesting_dump.sql"
```